# How to efficiently count filtered documents in MongoDB $group operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

I have a fairly small dataset of 63k documents (2.5GB total). Example of document:

```
{
     _id : "[uniqueId]",
     FormId : 10,
     Name : "Name of form",
     IsComplete : true,
     Sections : [ many sections and can be large ]
}
```

I want to get the total count of documents by FormId. I get fast result (.15sec) on this query:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
     { $sort : { FormId : 1 } }, //Index exists on FormId
     { $group : { _id : "$FormId", count : { $sum : 1 } } },
     { $sort : { "count" : -1 } }
])
```

My problem is I need to get a count of the documents where { "IsComplete":true }. I have 2 indexes built on both properties but I realize that using the $match operator scans all docs. So how does one efficiently filter the $group count?

Comment: You do not need the first `$sort` stage here.

Comment: @Styvane without the $sort stage $group takes 10 seconds to complete. Why would that happen? Starting with $sort uses index.

Answer (score 4):

Efficient Way would be

Filters down the documents by using $match to pass only matching documents to the next pipeline. By placing $match at the very beginning of a pipeline, the query can take advantage of indexes.

Use $project to pass along the documents with only the required fields to the next stage in the pipeline, this will further reduce data to the next pipeline.

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([ 
  { $match: {"IsComplete":true} },
  { $project: {"IsComplete":1, "FormId":1}},
  { $group : { _id : "$FormId", count : { $sum : 1 } } },
  { $sort : { "count" : -1 } }
])
```

Comment: When I run $match first the pipeline takes over 10 seconds to complete. I have 2 separate indexes on FormId and IsComplete. Why would it take so long to complete?

Comment: As Index on "IsComplete" does not have many unique values, indexing a field with a low number of distinct values is not really worth doing.The other factor is how well does the index divide your data, If you have about half true's and half false's, then it will help.

Comment: Performance here will also depend on the ratio of values of "IsComplete" and the value against you hitting the query, if you hitting query for true and ratio of data is 30:70 against true:false then it may reduce some time as it will be dealing with small set of data only.

Comment: A majority of documents will be IsComplete : true.

Comment: Then I don't think so that you will get performance boost in this case, things then become dependent on system h/w resources.